# Internet Explorer 11 resets PHP session on 5th tab

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, internet-explorer-11

Ok this is one of the odder issues I have run into.

We have a company Intranet site.  Many of our employees need to open several of our Intranet PHP pages at the same time, sharing PHP session variables (branch, etc.) between all of the pages.  They were complaining that they were losing sessions and I was able to determine that, regardless of which page is opened, whenever they opened a 5th tab, if the page has the session_start() function it would basically reset the session for all of the open pages.  All of the old session variables would be killed and the only ones available would be ones created on that page.

This ONLY happens on Internet Explorer 11 as far as I can tell.  We have a few machines still on 10 and they can open more than 5 tabs without this issue.  Although they might have different settings as well, I haven't looked into all of that yet.

I would personally love to use a different browser like Firefox or Chrome but they need to use Internet Explorer for a variety of things.

Anyone have any idea what to do?  I tried looking around and found some information on tab processes and such that looks like it might be the right fix, but it is a bit confusing.

Comment: the sessions are loaded by checking the cookie PHPSESSID (or called something else if expose_php is off in php.ini), is IE11 still sending that cookie on 5th tab? (if IE11 is not, then PHP is not actually deleting the session, its just IE11 telling it not to load that session anymore, effectively making PHP create a brand new session for it, as if it was a different person)

Comment: We actually figured this out, tab processes turned out to be the right track.  Basically there is a variable X at which, when IE hits it, starts a new session.  The default was set to 5, so we changed it.  Had to be changed in the registry though.  Annoying.